# Using FindWindows multiple times in a C++ Program?

Tags: c++, winapi

I use the following code(C++) to get the handle of a window (another application) and send message to one of the buttons to simulate a click and it works without any problem.

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumChildProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam) {

    mdv.test_list[mdv.counter] = hwnd;
    mdv.counter++;

    return TRUE;
}

void MDV::Jog()
{
    HWND WindowHandle;
    WindowHandle = FindWindow(NULL,L"Jog Program");
    EnumChildWindows(WindowHandle, EnumChildProc, 0);
    SendMessage(mdv.test_list[25], BM_CLICK, 0, 0);
}
```

However this results in a new pop up window (caption: Warning) with two buttons yes and no. I want to pick yes and tried the following

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumChildProc_YN(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam) {

    mdv.list_yn[mdv.counter_yn] = hwnd;
    mdv.counter_yn++;

    return TRUE;
}

BOOL CALLBACK EnumChildProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam) {

    mdv.test_list[mdv.counter] = hwnd;
    mdv.counter++;

    return TRUE;
}

void MDV::Jog()
{
    HWND WindowHandle;
    WindowHandle = FindWindow(NULL,L"Jog Program");
    EnumChildWindows(WindowHandle, EnumChildProc, 0);
    SendMessage(mdv.test_list[25], BM_CLICK, 0, 0);

    HWND YNHandle;
    YNHandle = FindWindow(NULL, L"Warning");
    EnumChildWindows(YNHandle, EnumChildProc_YN, 0);
    SendMessage(mdv.list_yn[0], BM_CLICK, 0, 0);

}
```

But it does not simulate the second click. I am relatively new to win32 API. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The primary interface for automating a UI is [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32).

Comment: Without seeing the actual window in question, it is difficult to answer this. We can't see if you are sending the `BM_CLICK` message to the correct HWND, or even if that HWND is a standard button that supports `BM_CLICK`. However, for standard modal popup dialogs like `MessageBox()`, rather than click on individual buttons, you could instead simulate a `BN_CLICKED` notification to the dialog window itself, where the `LOWORD(wParam)` is the ID of the button, which for standard dialogs will be IDs like `IDYES` (6), etc.

Comment: @RemyLebeau as I mentioned in the post, the first click is successfully simulated, but the second FindWindow is not getting executed at all.

Comment: You are calling `FindWindow` before the dialog even had a chance of getting created. If you want to be notified about dialogs getting created, use [WinEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/what-are-winevents).

Comment: @Newbieee16 you are just repeating what you already said. That doesn't change what I said. What have you done so far to try to debug the issue yourself? Did you check that `FindWindow()` is not returning NULL? Did you check that `EnumChildWindows()` is actually finding the button you want to click on? Did you check that button is actually the 1st HWND stored in `mdv.list_yn`? How are you determining which array elements you should be looking at? Are you using a tool like Spy++ for that? Why are your callbacks populating arrays at all and not directly outputting the specific HWNDs you want?

Comment: If you know what the default button option is and the window has focus, you can also directly use [`SendInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) to simulate the `space`/`enter` key to click the button (simulate `tab`/`<-`/`->` to select another button).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Comment pointed out, you could use [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32) instead of sending click message to the button.
Take the dialog of messagebox as an example:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <oleacc.h>
#include <UIAutomation.h>
using namespace std;

HWINEVENTHOOK  EventHook = (HWINEVENTHOOK)-1;
IUIAutomation* pClientUIA;
HRESULT click_window(HWND hwnd)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    IUIAutomationElement* pElement;
    hr = pClientUIA->ElementFromHandle(hwnd, &pElement);
    if (S_OK != hr)
    {
        printf("ElementFromHandle error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        return hr;
    }

    IInvokeProvider* pPattern;
    hr = pElement->GetCurrentPattern(UIA_InvokePatternId, (IUnknown**)&pPattern);
    if (S_OK != hr)
    {
        printf("GetCurrentPattern error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        return hr;
    }

    hr = pPattern->Invoke();
    if (S_OK != hr)
    {
        printf("Invoke error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        return hr;
    }
    return hr;
}
void __stdcall Wineventproc(HWINEVENTHOOK hWinEventHook, DWORD event, HWND hwnd, LONG idObject, LONG idChild, DWORD idEventThread, DWORD dwmsEventTime)
{
    if (event == EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE)
    {
        IAccessible* pIAccessible = NULL;
        VARIANT var;
        HRESULT hr = AccessibleObjectFromEvent(hwnd, idObject, idChild, &pIAccessible, &var);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && pIAccessible)
        {
            BSTR str;
            hr = pIAccessible->get_accName(var, &str);
            if (S_OK != hr)
            {
                printf("get_accName error: %d\n", GetLastError());
                return;
            }
            wprintf(L"%s\n", str);
            if (wcscmp(str, L"Yes") == 0) // choose the button option you want to click
            {
                hr = click_window(hwnd);
                PostQuitMessage(0);
            }
            SysFreeString(str);
        }
    }
}

DWORD WINAPI SetHook(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    if (!(EventHook = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE, EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE, NULL, Wineventproc, 0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS)))
    {
        int i = GetLastError();
        cout << "Failed to install MouseHook hook!   " << i << endl;
        return FALSE;
    }
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    UnhookWinEvent(EventHook);
    return TRUE;
}

static HWND hbutton = 0;
BOOL CALLBACK EnumChildProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam) {

    TCHAR name[255] = {};
    SendMessage(hwnd,WM_GETTEXT,255,(LPARAM)name);
    if (_tcscmp(name, L"Button_Name") == 0)
    {
        hbutton = hwnd;
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

int main()
{
    CoInitialize(0);
    DWORD tid;
    HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, SetHook, 0, 0, &tid); // wait for the dialog created event. 
    HRESULT hr;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CUIAutomation, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IUIAutomation, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pClientUIA));
    if (S_OK != hr)
    {
        printf("CoCreateInstance error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        return FALSE;
    }

    HWND WindowHandle;
    WindowHandle = FindWindow(NULL, L"Jog Program");
    EnumChildWindows(WindowHandle, EnumChildProc, 0);

    // make sure the event hook has been successfully or failed to set.
    while (EventHook != (HWINEVENTHOOK)-1); 
    if (EventHook)
    {
        click_window(hbutton);
    }
    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
    CoUninitialize();
}
```